# Class not found in behat featurecontext.php

Tags: behat, classnotfound

- after running, i am getting 
  Fatal error: Cannot declare class JsonApiContext because the name is already in use in C:\behat\newapi\vendor\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php on line 13

can anyone please help me on same ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information: could you show the code of the involved source files?

Comment: @Kariem here are my files
'composer.json' http://prntscr.com/bgl9l1
'behat.yml'  http://prntscr.com/bgl9of
'featurecontext' http://prntscr.com/bgl9s4

Comment: Edit the question and include the files, so that everything can be seen in one place. This makes it easier for everyone to see how the elements are linked.

Comment: @Kariem

Composer.json

{
  "require-dev" : {
    "behat/behat" : "3.0.*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver" : "*",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver" : "*",
    "behat/mink-extension" : "2.0.1",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver" : "*",
    "behat/mink" : "*",
    "drupal/drupal-extension": "~3.0",
    "behat/common-contexts": "*"
  },
  "require" : {
    "kriswallsmith/buzz" : "~0.14",
    "kielabokkie/jsonapi-behat-extension": "1.0.*@beta"
  }
}

________________________________________

Comment: @Kariem My behat.yml is too long and stackoverflow comment doesn't allow me to paste it here. 
Please suggest

Comment: @Kariem I am referring link :
https://packagist.org/packages/kielabokkie/jsonapi-behat-extension

Comment: I cannot access the images. Please, edit the question, i.e. click the _edit_ link below your question (or click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37830113/edit)) and add your snippets. Don't paste code in the comments - there won't be enough space.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the extends inheritance with a different class do you still get the error message?

Have you tried with "implements" instead of "extends"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JsonApiContext`.

In your FeatureContext.php it shall look like
class FeatureContext extends JsonApiContext ....